# How to handle back references in a parser?

Tags: c#, xaml, parsing, compiler-construction

I'm working on a XAML parser. I would like to make it as context-free as possible.

You know XAML is similar to plain XML, but with properties and extensibility in mind (value conversion, templates, markup extensions, named references between elements...)

Currently, I'm having a big problem: the XAML specification allows **nodes to be named** and usually there are properties **can depend on those names**.

Consider this XAML:

```
<Parent x:Name="MyParent">
   <Setter Target="MyParent.Background" Value="Red" />
</Parent>
```

In this snippet you can see that the `Target` property will have to "wait" until the Parent is created to be able to deliver a value. The concept of waiting sounds to me like a Task (a promise) that may be resolved at a later time, but it seems complex and may be an overkill.

To understand the problem it's important to notice that, as a design decision, I made my parser to inflate children elements **before** the parent elements.

For instance:

```
<Parent>
   <Child1/>
   <Child2/>
</Parent>
```

The instances `Child1` and `Child2` are fully initialized before the instance of Parent is created.

Now that I have explained how it works, how could I handle those references between nodes? References from parent => child will work, but not the opposite, because parents are created after all their children are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same as any compiler: When you see a reference to any given identifier `Foo` that hasn't been defined yet, stick an object in a Dictionary. The object goes under "Foo" in the dictionary and has a list of references to spots where `Foo` is referenced.

Once you've got everything defined, go back through that dictionary and fill in all the references. If anything's missing, issue an error. If any identifiers get defined twice in the same name space along the way, issue an error. If `Foo` is defined only once but is of an inappropriate type for a reference to it, issue an error.

Once you've got all that stuff together in whatever intermediate structure you're using, hand the intermediate structure over to the code that does the final pass and generates your UI, bytecode, binary, or whatever.

If you can have multiple scopes (and you will if you're not writing a toy), this gets more complicated. You'll need to have one identifier dictionary per scope and hang them off the parse tree for the code generator to grab as it goes along.

Comment: The alternative is to do two passes... One to collect the symbols, and one to generate everything